# How large a product out of 3 close-by factors need to be to avoid factorization?

Tags: prime-numbers, attack, factoring, safe-prime

For encryption a prime $P = 2 \cdot Q \cdot R \cdot S +1$ was used.
An adversary want to solve the discrete log problem $m \equiv g^i \bmod P$. For this he want to use the [Pholig-Hellmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) algorithm.
To use this he need the factorization of $P-1 = 2 \cdot  Q \cdot R \cdot S$.
Factor $2$ is trivial so he only need to know the primes $Q, R, S$

(edit)
He should also not be able to project a value $m$ into a subgroup, like:

$$m^{2\cdot R \cdot S} \equiv v \bmod P$$
$v$ is $1$ or has order $Q$
(edit end)

He does know prime $P$ and the internal structure of $P-1$ has $4$ factors and one of those is $2$. He also knows the other three factors are quite similar to eachother:
$$\frac{P-1}{2} \approx Q^3 \approx R^3 \approx S^3$$
with
$$ \max(Q,R,S) \le 1.25\cdot\min(Q,R,S)$$
or
$$\forall a,b,c \in \{Q,R,S\}: 0.8\cdot a \le b \le 1.25 \cdot c$$

edit2: That means the potential factors are in limited range between $\sqrt[3]{(P/(1.25^2))}$ and $\sqrt[3]{P}$

---

For values consisting out of two factors the current record is afaik about 240 decimal digits or 795-bit ([records-wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization_records))

---

**Question:** How large need to be a value out of three prime factors as described above to be as secure as the current record for two factors?

($Q,R,S,P$ can be set to special kind of primes, like safe primes, as long those conditions from above hold )

Comment: Security of discrete log is not related to factoring. You can directly assume that the adversary has the factorization.

Comment: @kelalaka fastest way to solve such a discrete log is afaik Pholig-Hellmann algorithm which needs to know the factorization of $P-1$. If he dont know the factorization it will take way longer to solve it. Or did got something wrong? If a generator with e.g. order $Q$ is given. Would it be faster to find his order than factorizing $P-1$?

Comment: Do you want to increase the prime sizes since you fear of factoring? Then not able to solve the dLog since that already infeasible!

Comment: Note that the runtime of Pohlig-Hellman is roughly $O(\sqrt Q+\sqrt R+\sqrt S)$ in your case. As the product still needs to be at least 1000 bit long, each factor needs to be at least 333 bits long and so the runtime of Pohlig-Hellman would be roughly $2^{160}$ which is infeasible.

Comment: @kelalaka you are correct. The main reason is not be able to project one value to another subgroup. (did some edit)

Comment: @SEJPM according to [disc. log records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm_records) a disc. log with 596 bits has been solved (safe prime).

Comment: @J.Doe this record used the number field sieve which scales much better but only against the order of the entire group, which in your case is $2QRS$, also [the current record should be 768 bits](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/067).

Comment: @SEJPM entire group = this group generated by the generator or all values $\bmod P$? In target app there will be 3 generator $q,r,s$ with order $Q,R,S$. So each represents only a subgroup.